# RP with very small error = P

Tags: computability, probabilistic-algorithms, probabilistic-turing-machines

I was asked to show the equality $ RP(1 − 2^{-2^{n}}) = P $, which seems wrong to me (?).

The $ \supseteq $ direction is obvious, and I want to show the other direction.

My first intuition was to run the algorithm that gives a false negative with probability $ 1-2^{-2^{n}} $ for $ n $ iterations, which will get me really close to 1, but I won't ever really reach 1 this way, so I am pretty much lost.

Comment: I toss $n$ fair coins, and depending on the result, I output a bit. The probability that I output 0 is less than $2^{-n}$. Do I ever output 0?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well, the number of possible outputs is $ 2^n $. so if you output a bit solely depending to the coins toss result and the probability to output 0 is strictly less than $2^{-n}$, you never output 0. I get the intuition behind your comment, but I am not sure how to formalize it.

Comment: The probability of each outcome in the coin toss space is $2^{-n}$, and so the probability of each event is either zero or at least $2^{-n}$.